# Oracle Hotspot JVM: generally, what operations are especially CPU-costly?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I'd like to understand of what types of operations contribute disproportionately to CPU load as well as develop an intuition on relative cost of common operations. To minimize generalizations, please assume Oracle 7 HotSpot JVM.

For example:

- does constructing lots of objects cost CPU (I understand it costs memory :-) )?
- does contenting for a monitor cost CPU? ie if we have multiple threads attempting to enter the same synchronized block, do blocked threads also consume CPU cycles?
- relative cost of above operations? For example, "new'ing a single object costs the same CPU as iterating over a X-element array"

Any tips on developing an intuition of relative CPU cost of typical operations?

Any good reads on the subject you could recommend?

thank you,

**CLARIFICATION**

thanks for early responses, but please note I:

- am NOT asking 'why is my app slow'
- understand that using a profiler will help identify problems in a specific app and that for example, GC can eat up CPU or that GC'ing tenured generation is more costly than Eden space
- understand that most ops become costly only if executed a lot (ie virtually no op is expensive if used sparingly)

Instead, I am looking for guidance of *relative* CPU cost, especially w.r.t. above operations (let's assume a 'web-scale' app uses all ops mentioned equal amount - a lot).

For example I already now that:

- long method call chains do not contribute significantly to CPU load (so it's generally OK to use method delegation liberally)
- throwing exceptions is more expensive than using conditionals (thus latter is generally preferred for flow-control in highly performance-sensitive code)

...but what about instantiating new objects or contenting for a monitor? Would either of these ops be significant (dominant?) contributors to CPU load (let's say I don't care about latency or heap size) at scale?

Comment: XML processing (parsing, transforming, marshalling), IO operations are a couple I can think of.

Comment: Excessive GC may cause high CPU load, check it with `-verbose:gc`.

Comment: we profiled our app - GC is < 2% of overall CPU time

Comment: Didn't you learn from profiling the code what consumes CPU?

Comment: Contending for a lock doesn't consume CPU, that's for sure. The OS will simply decide which thread can acquire a lock once it is free; the others will just go on waiting.

Comment: Memory allocation is virtually free CPU-wise, but `new` could imply much more than that. For example, instantiating `Calendar` is heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that among you wrote the relative CPU consumption is follows:

1) indexing of an array; it's fast; it's just addressing

2) monitor -- slower; suspended and waiting threads do not consume CPU, switching consumes very little CPU, but more than indexing

3) creating an object may be slow if an object is complex and causes sub-objects creation; creating a single `new Object()` just slightly slower than thread switching; but may be I am wrong and it is the same; anyway comparable

4) throwing/catching an exception is VERY slow; it is 10-100 times slower that creating an object

Comment: If throwing and catching exceptions is very slow, is it not better performance-wise to return an error type or something similar instead of throwing exceptions? Perhaps an object array containing your actual return value and/or an error type?

Comment: @LoganDam exceptions should occur rarely by definition; if in your case exceptions occur often, then sure -- you should use returned error mark...

Comment: Note that indexing into an array includes a bounds-check by the VM, unless it can determine that a check is unnecessary based on some heuristics.  You can bypass this entirely by use of sun.misc.Unsafe, if you're feeling semi-unportable and risque (I believe there is an initiative to standardize sun.misc.Unsafe in a future JDK).  Not recommended unless what you're doing is performance critical, you've profiled to be sure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A single operation is always fast. A measurable CPU load an operation is executed several thousand times or even a million or billion times. So you want to watch out for all kinds of loop and heavily recursive calls.

Often, it's not obvious that that something is executed a million time because the obvious loop is only executed a hundred times. But it calls a function that executes something a hundred times, which contains another function executing an operation a hundred time. That way you end up with something being run a million times. And in a web app, it's multiplied with the number of concurrent requests.

Since it's not easy to spot the real hot spots, you probably want to use a special performance analysis tool for Java to investigate your application. That way you learn what patterns are CPU-intensive and what patterns are not.

Another thing in Java, if you allocate a lot of memory (be it few large chunks and many small chunks) that cannot quickly be release, then garbage collection can become a CPU hog. Using tons of string (e.g. when processing XML) can be such a cause.

But the best thing really is to use a tool for analysis.

Comment: thanks, but that wasn't my question, Codo (perhaps it is poorly worded). We did profile our app; I understand that virtually no op is expensive if executed once. My question is about *relative* cost: what's more CPU costly (say each is done 1m times): a) new Object() b) throw Exception c) some other op

Comment: @Nikita I think the problem you will run in to is that such microbenchmarking is subject to a lot of variables at runtime. Different OS and hardware combos can give different relative results. Also different program states can effect certain things like how far does a throw unwind the stack before its caught or when allocating a new object does the VM have to allocate more memory, how complex is the constructor. It is difficult to generalize, which is why optimization is hard and should be done with proper profiling of the specific application being optimized.

Comment: fair enough, @Dev, i understand there is no 100% accurate answer. But one can still make *some* generalizations - subject to exceptions ;- - with some assumptions, i.e. "all ops run on the same hardware; allocated heap size is fixed" etc

Answer (score 1):

Throwing an exception can be very cheap. The expensive part is usually only the creation of the exception object, because this calls `fillInStackTrace()`, which is expensive. If you omit this, the rest is fast (it can be as fast as a goto in C).

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/longjumps_considered_inexpensive

Here is a [page with internals about the OpenJDK JVM that lists information about performance](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques) for further information.